# Use inotifywait and lftp to synchronize servers

Tags: linux, bash, inotify, ftp

I have two servers:

- Server A (CentOS), where people can upload files to (upload root is /files)
- Server B (Win 2008), with FileZilla FTP Server (FTP root is C:\content)

I want that whenever a file is uploaded to Server A, to any subfolder under /files, the file is automatically copied to the exact same subfolder on Server B. Thus, if a user uploads "flowers.jpg" to /files/photos/12345/ then the file must be copied over FTP to C:\content\photos\12345

So far I have this bash script, it does copy the files to server B, but all files are placed in C:\content, and not in the corresponding subfolders. Who can help me find the correct syntax?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /files

inotifywait -q -r -m -e close_write,moved_to . --format %w%f | 
  while read FILE; do
    lftp -e "put $FILE; exit" -u user,password -p 2121 ftp.server-a.com
  done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the FTP command `put $FILE` will put the file `$FILE` into whatever the 'current directory' is in the FTP Server side; hence, into the root directory of the FTP Server (which is located in C:\content).

You need to first extract the subdirectory from `inotifywait`'s `%w` output, then prepend a `cd` FTP command to the `lftp` parameter.

I have never used `inotifywait` before, but I think the script should be like this:

```
inotifywait -q -r -m -e close_write,moved_to . --format "%w %f" | 
  while read DIR FILE; do
    lftp -e "cd $DIR; put $FILE; exit" -u user,password -p 2121 ftp.server-a.com
  done
```

***PS:*** It's never a good idea to explicitly write a password in a script. Use `rsync` instead; on Windows, you'll need to install an `rsync` server. I personally use Cygwin, and use `cygrunsrv` to make `rsync` run as a Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the rsync tip; I assume you mean something like rsync over SSH with public/private keys, so that you never need to store a user/pass anywhere on the server (see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id)

Comment: ah, yes, forgot to mention the public keys, hehe :-)

Comment: lftp supports SFTP as well, so you don't necessarily need to switch to rsync in order to use private SSH key based authentication. All you have to do is provide lftp with a `sftp://host` url, where `host` can also be an alias you've defined in `~/.ssh/config` with key options, user names, and any other ssh options you may need.

Answer (score 1):

@pepoluan gave me the answer, but I wanted to inform about the script I ended up with, which is slightly different (reason I did this in an answer and not in a comment: you can't markup code in a comment)

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /files
inotifywait -q -r -m -e close_write,moved_to . --format "%w %w%f" |
  while read DIR FILE; do
    lftp -e "mkdir -p $DIR; cd $DIR; put $FILE; exit" -u user,pass -p 2121 ftp.server-a.com
  done
```